# Is it possible to use Amplify federatedSignIn in popup? (web)

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, aws-amplify

We're building a React app and use AWS Amplify to manage authentication.

For SSO we're using Google and Office365.
By default Amplify's `Auth.federatedSignIn` redirects to the provider's login page, but we want to open it in a popup.

For example, there is own Google authentication library that has property `ux_mode: 'popup'` in config, which allows to do exactly that, but I cannot find a way to force Amplify to do it.

Thanks.